# How to refill the component with filtered data in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, filtering

I have specific kind of situation here. I'm filtering scope of data not only with help of parameters, but with help of routes as well. Therefore, I can't use ActivatedRoute since it only helps with parameters. But here is the deal: I have several routes. Each of them fills the same component with data. The only difference between them is that only on the /start route you don't have subcategories sidebar. These routes are /start (all items), /sport (sport category items), /sport/football (category sport, subcategory football) and couple of similar routes that filters items to levels of category or subcategory. Category filtering works fine. But I just can't find a way to refill the component when route changes to /category/subcategory. I managed to navigate to the correct url that includes subcategory without reloading, but nothing changes on any route that includes subcategory. It simply doesn't do additional filtering. It doesn't change the scope of data that is on display. I'll provide code down bellow.

```
app-routing.module.ts:

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/start",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "start",
    component: StoriesComponent
  },
  {
    path: "informative",
    component: StoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "politics",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
      {
        path: "chronicle",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "sport",
    component: StoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "football",
        component: StoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "culture",
    component: StoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "acting",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
      {
        path: "society",
        component: StoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "economics",
    component: StoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "industry",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
      {
        path: "energetics",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
      {
        path: "tourism",
        component: StoriesComponent
      },
      {
        path: "informatics-and-telecommunications",
        component: StoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "economic-propaganda",
    component: EconomicPropagandaComponent
  },
  {
    path: "personnel",
    component: PersonnelComponent
  },
  {
    path: "our-story",
    component: OurStoryComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    //onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


stories.component.ts:

import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Event, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IStory } from 'src/app/interfaces/i-story';
import { StoriesService } from 'src/app/services/stories.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stories',
  templateUrl: './stories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stories.component.css']
})
export class StoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  category:string;
  subcategory:string;
  //@Output() refreshData = new EventEmitter<{update:boolean}>();
  constructor(private storiesService:StoriesService, private router:Router) { 
    this.category=this.router.url;
    this.category = this.category.split("/")[1];
    if(this.category.includes("/")){
      this.subcategory = this.category.split("/")[1];
      if(this.subcategory.includes("?")){
        this.subcategory=this.subcategory.split("?")[0];
      }
    }
    if(this.category.includes("?")){
      this.category=this.category.split("?")[0];
    }
    this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event)=>{
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
        console.log('change');
        this.getStories();
        //this.refreshData.emit({update:true})
      }
    });
  }
  stories: IStory[] = [];
  private getStories(){
    if(this.category=="start"){
      this.storiesService.getAllStories().subscribe({
        next:data=>{
          this.stories=data
        },
        error: err=>{
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
    else if (this.subcategory==null){
      this.storiesService.getCategorizedStories(this.category).subscribe({
        next:data=>{
          this.stories=data
        },
        error: err=>{
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      this.storiesService.getSubcategorizedStories(this.category,this.subcategory).subscribe({
        next:data=>{
          this.stories=data
        },
        error: err=>{
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStories();
  }
  //ngChanges(): void{
  //  this.getStories();
  //}
}

stories.component.html:

<div>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="category!='start'">
        <app-subcategories-navigation [type]="category"></app-subcategories-navigation>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let s of stories">
        <div>
            <p>{{s.title}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>

subcategories-navigation.component.html

<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let n of navigation">
        <li>
            <!-- <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="{{n.routerLink}}">{{n.label}}</a> -->
            <a routerLinkActive="active" (click)="reload(n.routerLink)">{{n.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
<router-outlet name="sub"></router-outlet>

start-navigation.component.html:

<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let n of navigation">
        <li>
            <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="{{n.routerLink}}">{{n.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

subcategories-navigation.component.ts:

import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { INavigation } from 'src/app/interfaces/i-navigation';
import { NavigationService } from 'src/app/services/navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subcategories-navigation',
  templateUrl: './subcategories-navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subcategories-navigation.component.css']
})
export class SubcategoriesNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private navigationService:NavigationService, private router:Router) { }
  navigation: INavigation[] = [];
  @Input() type:string;
  //@Output() refreshEmiter = new EventEmitter<{update:boolean}>();
  reload(url:string){
    this.router.navigate([this.type+"/"+url]);
    //this.refreshEmiter.emit({update:true});
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navigationService.getNavigation(this.type).subscribe({
      next:data=>{
        this.navigation=data
      },
      error: err=>{
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }
}

start-navigation.component.ts:

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { INavigation } from 'src/app/interfaces/i-navigation';
import { NavigationService } from 'src/app/services/navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start-navigation',
  templateUrl: './start-navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start-navigation.component.css']
})
export class StartNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private navigationService:NavigationService) { }
  navigation: INavigation[] = [];
  readonly type:string = "start";
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navigationService.getNavigation(this.type).subscribe({
      next:data=>{
        this.navigation=data
      },
      error: err=>{
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }

}

app-component.html:

<app-start-navigation></app-start-navigation>
```